# How to pass xml in POST method?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, post, request

I have to pass xml in a request, but I cannot figure out how can I perform it :/. Can you please help me?

I've already stored and prepared the xml.

The request sample:

```
POST http://..... HTTP/1.0
Content-type: text/xml
```

and xml

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is the source and destination of your xml?

If your source is say a file, and your destination is say a servlet, you can use curl http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL to send the xml and a servlet to receive it.

The servlet 3.0 spec has new features for this kind of stuff so that should make it easy.

OR

Are you trying to send a post from your java application?

John : )

Comment: trying to send post from my app

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient

Following is the code I use to post xml to a server.

```
String payload = <XML String>
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://" + ip + ":" + port);
LOGGER.info("WebService Call for " + ip + ":" + port);

try {
      StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(payload);
      post.setEntity(entity);
      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
      HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
      EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
} finally {
    post.releaseConnection();
}
```